# get ICollectionView data type

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid in my `WPF` solution and its data-source is an `ICollectionView`. But in a onclick I want to find out the data source's System.type . How can I find the element type of the `ICollectionView` data-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
(this.yourGridName.ItemsSource as ICollectionView).SourceCollection.AsQueryable().ElementType == typeof(your_system_type)
```